# tidymodel recipe and `step_lag()`: Error when using `predict()`

Tags: r, tidymodels

This may be a usage misunderstanding, but I expect the following toy example to work.  I want to have a lagged predictor in my recipe, but once I include it in the recipe, and try to predict on the same data using a workflow with the recipe, it doesn't recognize the column `foo` and cannot compute its lag.

Now, I can get this to work if I:

1. Pull the fit out of the workflow that has been fit.
2. Independently prep and bake the data I want to fit.

Which I code after the failed workflow fit, and it succeeds.  According to the documentation, I should be able to put a workflow fit in the predict slot: https://www.tidymodels.org/start/recipes/#predict-workflow

I am probably fundamentally misunderstanding how workflow is supposed to operate.  I have what I consider a workaround, but I do not understand why the failed statement isn't working in the way the workaround is.  I expected the failed workflow construct to work under the covers like the workaround I have.

In short, if `work_df` is a dataframe, `the_rec` is a recipe based off `work_df`, `rf_mod` is a model, and you create the workflow `rf_workflow`, then should I expect the `predict()` function to work identically in the two `predict()` calls below?

```r
## Workflow
rf_workflow <-
    workflow() %>%
    add_model(rf_mod) %>%
    add_recipe(the_rec)

## fit
rf_workflow_fit <-
    rf_workflow %>%
    fit(data = work_df)

## Predict with workflow.  I expect since a workflow has a fit model and
## a recipe as part of it, it should know how to do the following:
predict(rf_workflow_fit, work_df)
#> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `lag_1_foo`.
#> x object 'foo' not found
#> i Input `lag_1_foo` is `dplyr::lag(x = foo, n = 1L, default = NA)`.


## Predict by explicitly prepping and baking the data, and pulling out the
## fit from the workflow:
predict(
    rf_workflow_fit %>%
        pull_workflow_fit(),
    bake(prep(the_rec), work_df))
#> # A tibble: 995 x 1
#>     .pred
#>     <dbl>
#>  1  2.24 
#>  2  0.595
#>  3  0.262
```

Full reprex example below.

```r
library(tidymodels)
#> -- Attaching packages -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- tidymodels 0.1.1 --
#> v broom     0.7.1      v recipes   0.1.13
#> v dials     0.0.9      v rsample   0.0.8 
#> v dplyr     1.0.2      v tibble    3.0.3 
#> v ggplot2   3.3.2      v tidyr     1.1.2 
#> v infer     0.5.3      v tune      0.1.1 
#> v modeldata 0.0.2      v workflows 0.2.1 
#> v parsnip   0.1.3      v yardstick 0.0.7 
#> v purrr     0.3.4
#> -- Conflicts ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- tidymodels_conflicts() --
#> x purrr::discard() masks scales::discard()
#> x dplyr::filter()  masks stats::filter()
#> x dplyr::lag()     masks stats::lag()
#> x recipes::step()  masks stats::step()
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)

### Create autocorrelated timeseries: https://stafoo.stackexchange.com/a/29242/17203
work_df <-
    tibble(
        foo = stats::filter(rnorm(1000), filter=rep(1,5), circular=TRUE) %>%
            as.numeric()
    )
# plot(work_df$foo)
work_df
#> # A tibble: 1,000 x 1
#>         foo
#>       <dbl>
#>  1 -0.00375
#>  2  0.589  
#>  3  0.968  
#>  4  3.24   
#>  5  3.93   
#>  6  1.11   
#>  7  0.353  
#>  8 -0.222  
#>  9 -0.713  
#> 10 -0.814  
#> # ... with 990 more rows

## Recipe
the_rec <-
    recipe(foo ~ ., data = work_df) %>%
    step_lag(foo, lag=1:5) %>%
    step_naomit(all_predictors())

the_rec %>% prep() %>% juice()
#> # A tibble: 995 x 6
#>       foo lag_1_foo lag_2_foo lag_3_foo lag_4_foo lag_5_foo
#>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#>  1  1.11      3.93      3.24      0.968     0.589  -0.00375
#>  2  0.353     1.11      3.93      3.24      0.968   0.589  
#>  3 -0.222     0.353     1.11      3.93      3.24    0.968  
#>  4 -0.713    -0.222     0.353     1.11      3.93    3.24   
#>  5 -0.814    -0.713    -0.222     0.353     1.11    3.93   
#>  6  0.852    -0.814    -0.713    -0.222     0.353   1.11   
#>  7  1.65      0.852    -0.814    -0.713    -0.222   0.353  
#>  8  1.54      1.65      0.852    -0.814    -0.713  -0.222  
#>  9  2.10      1.54      1.65      0.852    -0.814  -0.713  
#> 10  2.24      2.10      1.54      1.65      0.852  -0.814  
#> # ... with 985 more rows

## Model
rf_mod <-
    rand_forest(
        mtry = 4,
        trees = 1000,
        min_n = 13) %>%
    set_mode("regression") %>%
    set_engine("ranger")

## Workflow
rf_workflow <-
    workflow() %>%
    add_model(rf_mod) %>%
    add_recipe(the_rec)

## fit
rf_workflow_fit <-
    rf_workflow %>%
    fit(data = work_df)

## Predict
predict(rf_workflow_fit, work_df)
#> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `lag_1_foo`.
#> x object 'foo' not found
#> i Input `lag_1_foo` is `dplyr::lag(x = foo, n = 1L, default = NA)`.


## Perhaps I just need to pull off the fit and work with that?... Nope.
predict(
    rf_workflow_fit %>%
        pull_workflow_fit(),
    work_df)
#> Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
#> x Columns `lag_1_foo`, `lag_2_foo`, `lag_3_foo`, `lag_4_foo`, and `lag_5_foo` don't exist.

## Maybe I need to bake it first... and that works.
## But doesn't that defeat the purpose of a workflow?
predict(
    rf_workflow_fit %>%
        pull_workflow_fit(),
    bake(prep(the_rec), work_df))
#> # A tibble: 995 x 1
#>     .pred
#>     <dbl>
#>  1  2.24 
#>  2  0.595
#>  3  0.262
#>  4 -0.977
#>  5 -1.24 
#>  6 -0.140
#>  7  1.36 
#>  8  1.30 
#>  9  1.78 
#> 10  2.42 
#> # ... with 985 more rows

## Session info
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> - Session info ---------------------------------------------------------------
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
#>  os       Windows 10 x64              
#>  system   x86_64, mingw32             
#>  ui       RTerm                       
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  English_United States.1252  
#>  ctype    English_United States.1252  
#>  tz       America/Chicago             
#>  date     2020-10-13                  
#> 
#> - Packages -------------------------------------------------------------------
#>  package     * version    date       lib source        
#>  assertthat    0.2.1      2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  backports     1.1.10     2020-09-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  broom       * 0.7.1      2020-10-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  class         7.3-15     2019-01-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  cli           2.0.2      2020-02-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  codetools     0.2-16     2018-12-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  colorspace    1.4-1      2019-03-18 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  crayon        1.3.4      2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  dials       * 0.0.9      2020-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  DiceDesign    1.8-1      2019-07-31 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  digest        0.6.25     2020-02-23 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  dplyr       * 1.0.2      2020-08-18 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  ellipsis      0.3.1      2020-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  evaluate      0.14       2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  fansi         0.4.1      2020-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  foreach       1.5.0      2020-03-30 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  furrr         0.1.0      2018-05-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  future        1.19.1     2020-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  generics      0.0.2      2018-11-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  ggplot2     * 3.3.2      2020-06-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  globals       0.13.0     2020-09-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  glue          1.4.2      2020-08-27 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  gower         0.2.2      2020-06-23 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  GPfit         1.0-8      2019-02-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  gtable        0.3.0      2019-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  hardhat       0.1.4      2020-07-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  highr         0.8        2019-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  htmltools     0.5.0      2020-06-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  infer       * 0.5.3      2020-07-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  ipred         0.9-9      2019-04-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  iterators     1.0.12     2019-07-26 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  knitr         1.30       2020-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  lattice       0.20-38    2018-11-04 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  lava          1.6.8      2020-09-26 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  lhs           1.1.1      2020-10-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  lifecycle     0.2.0      2020-03-06 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  listenv       0.8.0      2019-12-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  lubridate     1.7.9      2020-06-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  magrittr      1.5        2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  MASS          7.3-51.5   2019-12-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  Matrix        1.2-18     2019-11-27 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  modeldata   * 0.0.2      2020-06-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  munsell       0.5.0      2018-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  nnet          7.3-12     2016-02-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  parsnip     * 0.1.3      2020-08-04 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  pillar        1.4.6      2020-07-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  pkgconfig     2.0.3      2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  plyr          1.8.6      2020-03-03 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  pROC          1.16.2     2020-03-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  prodlim       2019.11.13 2019-11-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  purrr       * 0.3.4      2020-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  R6            2.4.1      2019-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  ranger        0.12.1     2020-01-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  Rcpp          1.0.5      2020-07-06 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  recipes     * 0.1.13     2020-06-23 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  rlang         0.4.7      2020-07-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  rmarkdown     2.4        2020-09-30 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  rpart         4.1-15     2019-04-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  rsample     * 0.0.8      2020-09-23 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  rstudioapi    0.11       2020-02-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  scales      * 1.1.1      2020-05-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  sessioninfo   1.1.1      2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  stringi       1.5.3      2020-09-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  stringr       1.4.0      2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  survival      3.1-8      2019-12-03 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  tibble      * 3.0.3      2020-07-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  tidymodels  * 0.1.1      2020-07-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  tidyr       * 1.1.2      2020-08-27 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  tidyselect    1.1.0      2020-05-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  timeDate      3043.102   2018-02-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  tune        * 0.1.1      2020-07-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  utf8          1.1.4      2018-05-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  vctrs         0.3.4      2020-08-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  withr         2.3.0      2020-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  workflows   * 0.2.1      2020-10-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  xfun          0.18       2020-09-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  yaml          2.2.1      2020-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  yardstick   * 0.0.7      2020-07-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#> 
#> [1] C:/Users/IRINZN/Documents/R/R-3.6.3/library
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I reproduced your code and had the same error. I can't see a problem with the code usage. May be a more experienced user or someone from tidymodels can support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are experiencing an error is that you have created a predictor variable from the **outcome**. When it comes time to predict on new data, the outcome is not available; we are *predicting* the outcome for new data, not assuming that it is there already.

This is a fairly strong assumption of the tidymodels framework, for either modeling or preprocessing, to protect against information leakage. You can read [about this a bit more here](https://www.tmwr.org/recipes.html#skip-equals-true).

It's possible you already know about these resources, but if you are working with time series models, I'd suggest checking out these resources:

- [Resampling for time series](https://www.tidymodels.org/learn/models/time-series/)
- [Using timetk for time series preprocessing](https://business-science.github.io/timetk/articles/TK03_Forecasting_Using_Time_Series_Signature.html)
- [Using modeltime for time series modeling](https://business-science.github.io/modeltime/)

Comment: Was not aware of those resources, I will now look, thanks!

Comment: I think the key advice from your first link is in that box: "For simple transformations of the outcome column(s), we strongly suggest that those operations be conducted outside of the recipe."  I have a legit reason to use the lagged outcome variable (analagous to a temperature), and it is reasonable to have prior measurements to help predict the next temperature.  So I will have to pre-process those features, which seems legit based on what you want from recipes and workflows.

Comment: Ah, then you might go with `dplyr::lag()` and consider this not part of the statistical transformations in recipes. We appreciate you sharing what you're doing because it helps to know what people are doing in the real world.

Comment: My pleasure, I get the best end of the deal using your tools.  For my part, then, I hadn't seen your links -- on first blush, it appears to overlap with things like {fable}, and I have been following that because this is my reference: https://otexts.com/fpp3/ .  The thing I'm trying to do now is to sequence models -- one where I have a rand_forest that has some lags, with outcomes and regressors.  And then since there is a autocorrelated error, I want an ARIMA or something like it to post-process errors and adapt faster.  I'll also take suggestions on models that bake that in...

Comment: I agree with @mpettis. There are many situations when having lagged outcomes is desirable. I spent a lot of time trying to figure out this same error until I saw this post.  It would be great if this could be implemented as part of the recipe step.